# Add a column header row if not exist in PHP

Tags: php

I have an html form on my web site. When the form is filled out and the submit button is clicked the data is stored on my server in a csv text file. I want to add a column header row if it doesn't exist. My code adds the header each time new data is entered whether it exists or not, even though I have an if statement that says add if the header row does not exist. What do I need to change so that the column header row only gets added if it doesn't exist?

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$yourzip = $_POST['yourzip'];
$header = "Name,address,city,zip\r\n";
$fp = fopen("protected/RaceName_2022-04-26_EntryList.txt", "a");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    if(!file_exists($header)) {
    fwrite($fp, $header);
    }
$savestring = $fname . "," . $address . "," . $city . "," . $yourzip . "\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}
else {
    echo "Error locking file!";
}
fclose($fp);
echo "Data has been saved in <b><i>protected</i></b> folder";
?>
...
```

Comment: `if(!file_exists($header)) {` checks if a file `"Name,address,city,zip\r\n"` exists - which doesn't.

Comment: You might want to explore other options, such as... (1) When you first create the file, write the header.  In later operations, if the file already exists, assume the header is present.  (2) Don't use a header at all, just treat the file as data and interpret it accordingly in the application.  (3) Use a database, which more effectively separates data from schema (which is what you're trying to do manually here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggling I got it right. First check if the file exists before opening, if not add the header. Here is the code that works as expected.

```
$exists = file_exists("protected/RaceName_2022-04-26_EntryList.txt");
$header = "fName,address,city,yourzip\r";
$fp = fopen("protected/RaceName_2022-04-26_EntryList.txt", "a");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
if (!$exists) {
    fwrite($fp, $header);
}
$savestring = $fname . "," . $address . "," . $city . "," . 
$yourzip . "\r";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}
```

Note, the end of the $header string, \r, not \r\n, also the end of the $savestring, \r not \r\n. With the \n removed the line spacing is single. With the \r\n the line spacing is double.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php.

First add header then add with "a"

```
$fh = fopen("a.txt", "r+");
fwrite($fh, $header);
fclose($fh);
```